# Cordova Javascript Documentation

Tags: javascript, cordova, documentation

Is there any documentation tool for Cordova Javascript?

I've tried JsDoc 2.4.0, but it's not working.
JsDoc does not recognize annotation tags in my Cordova Javascript files.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution by myself. JsDoc works fine when @name tag exists.